# Error with Case Statement using a range of number

Tags: basic

I receive an error that states

> end statement expected

Should I be using something besides `to`? I've tried `or` and `&` and receive similar errors.

```
   Dim interp As String = ""
   Select Case BmiValue
      Case Is < 18.5
         interp = "Underweight"
      Case Is <18.5 to >=24.9
         interp = "Normal"
      Case Is <24.9 to >=29.9
         interp = "Overweight"
      Case Else >/= 30.0
         interp = "Obese"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `End Select` just after your code.

```
Dim interp As String = "" 
Select Case BmiValue 
   Case Is < 18.5 
      interp = "Underweight"           
   Case Is <18.5 to >=24.9 
      interp = "Normal" 
   Case Is <24.9 to >=29.9 
      interp = "Overweight" 
   Case Else >/= 30.0 
      interp = "Obese"
End Select
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion and still receive the same error. I'm going to try to copy/paste all my code and see if this helps with a resolution.    

    'Return interpretation of a BMI value
    Public Shared Function Interpret(ByVal BmiValue As Double) As String
        Dim interp As String = ""
        Select Case BmiValue
   Case Is < 18.5 interp = "Underweight"        
   Case Is <18.5 to >=24.9 interp = "Normal" 
   Case Is <24.9 to >=29.9 interp = "Overweight" 
   Case Else >/= 30.0 interp = "Obese"
        End Select
        Return interp
    End Function
End Class

Comment: The error still says 'end of statement expected' on all the 'case is' lines

Comment: I've edited my answer. You need to put the `interop = "string"` on a separate line.

Comment: Thank you Yusef! This is really new to me so your time helped a great deal!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!!!!! I took out the 'to' in each line and the '/' between >+ and it worked!!!! Have not idea why it worked this time and not the 100 other times I tried different things!!!!